# How to check server hard disk type via PHP

Tags: php, exec, hardware, hard-drive

I was looking for a way to check out the server hard disk type via PHP. But even after doing lot of searches I didn't get any clue about how to find it.

Actually what I want to do is to `echo` if the server hard disk is a mechanical hard disk or pure SSD.

Some hosting company uses mechanical hard drive for actual file server & database then use ssd cache layer on top of that. In this case I would like to show the server hard disk type as mechanical hard drive, as I don't wanna consider the caching layers.

Anyone got any idea about how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

If you run on a linux server, PHP can run shell scripts.

```
$output = shell_exec ('sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda' );
```

The command will give you the information you want, but you will need to parse it for specific things;
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-hard-disk-hardware-specs-on-linux/

Comment: Can  use just `/` instead of `/dev/sda` as I'm trying to write a general code and different server might have different partitioning ?

Comment: Also the link you provided, I don't see how it will show me whether I have mechanical hdd or or ssd? Can you please elaborate your answer more with a small snippet of example?

Comment: ok.. so by type you meant SSD or HDD, my bad. There is a command but it I can't guarantee you will find it on all distributions of linux.    "lsblk -d -o name,rota" -> "  NAME ROTA
sda     0
sdb     0
sdc     1", this will return the type of hdd. I don't have experience with a lot of servers, but for ubuntu this works.

Comment: Btw... ROTA 1 means hdd, 0 SSD